# Is it possible that a matrix depicts like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible for $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, that $$\frac{|Ax|}{|x|}>|\lambda_{max}|$$ where $\lambda_{max}$ is the biggest eigenvalue of A?

I know this can not happen, if there is a basis of eigenvectors, but in general?

EDIT:
So from the comments so far, I understood that the way to go may be to rewrite the LHS to $$\sqrt{\frac{x^* A^*Ax}{x^*x}}$$ and then use, that $A^*A$ is diagonalizable. But how then do I see, that $\sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}\leq\lambda_{max}$ (with $\rho$ being the spectral radius) without assuming anything about $A$?

Comment: This can happen even when there is a basis of eigenvectors. The matrix $$A=\pmatrix{2&100\cr0&1\cr}$$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$, so also a basis of eigenvectors. Yet $|Ax|/|x|>100$ when $x=(0,1)^T$. You need, for example, $A$ to be Hermitian to be sure that this inequality cannot happen.

Answer (score 0):

This can't happen. Note that $A^*A$ is diagonalizable- and hence there is a basis of eigenvectors, and the modulus of the maximum eigenvalue of $A$ is the (positive) square root of maximum eigenvalue of $A^*A$

Comment: The square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $A^*A$ is the maximum *singular value* of $A$, not the maximum eigenvalue (which need not be real).

Comment: @vadim123: well- I meant the modulus of the maximum eigenvalue. Let me edit it.

Comment: Still false -- see p.4 of http://www.mathworks.com/moler/eigs.pdf for an example.

Comment: @vadim123: I do not see the example... could you please elaborate? The statement I wrote is correct- the proof can be done by noting that eigenvalues of p(A) are p(\lambda) where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: The matrix has eigenvalues $1,2,3$ and singular values $817, 2.47, 0.003$.  In general the singular values agree with the eigenvalues only for special matrices.